# I have breakpoints in my eclipse project and i want to debugg my app but it giving error of "connection refused by VM"

Tags: eclipse-adt, connection-refused

I have breakpoints in my eclipse project and i want to debugg my app but it giving error of "connection refused by VM"

I am using windows 8.1(64 bit)
eclipse kepler(32 bit)
jdk 1.7(32 bit)

Comment: Is there any more information that you can give us? This is not enough information for us to help you solve your problem. What happened when you googled for the error message?

Comment: Have you tried again? It might be just a sporadic.

Comment: i googled error and it is asking for reset adb....i tried many times but not woking....when i debug app it stuck on screen "waiting for debugger